# How to check if modulus of 2 number is equal to 0 or not

Tags: c++, if-statement

Few days ago I wrote a program to check if a number have a square root with no decimal point. And I wrote a simple program code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

int checkforFloat(int x, int y)
{
    //will return 0 if no remainder remains, other value meaning has remainder
    return x%y;
}

int main()
{
    while(true)
    {
        std::cout << "Enter number to check if it has square root: ";
        double squareNumber{};
        std::cin >> squareNumber;

        double squareRoot{sqrt(squareNumber)};

        if(checkforFloat(squareNumber, squareRoot)==0)
        {
            std::cout<<"The number you entered has a square root number, and that is " << squareRoot << '\n';
        }
        else if(checkforFloat(squareNumber, squareRoot)!=0)
        {
            std::cout<<"Sorry, " << squareNumber << " has no square root.\n";
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

and the output for this program looks like this:

```
Enter number to check if it has square root: 25
The number you entered has a square root number, and that is 5
Enter number to check if it has square root: 24
The number you entered has a square root number, and that is 4.89898
Enter number to check if it has square root: 225
The number you entered has a square root number, and that is 15
Enter number to check if it has square root: 226
Sorry, 226 has no square root.
```

As you can see, this line is not working properly (or I am unable to understand where is the problem) `else if(checkforFloat(squareNumber, squareRoot)!=0)` I don't know what's going on but the thing what is going wrong with this program is it prints the square rooted number even if the square root is floating point number. In the other hand if I use int not double as data type for variable `squareNumber` and `squareRoot` it doesn't work for me. I'm not sure if the problem is in the `else if` statement or not. I'm new to `C++` so it's kinda hard for me to know what is going wrong.

Comment: Read about [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754). [Floating point numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic) are strange beasts. Compile your code with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) and all warnings and debug info: `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` then use the [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) debugger

Comment: A bit about style: `if (x) ... else if (!x) ...` can be written more simply as `if (x) ... else ...`. There's no need for that second call to `checkForFloat`.

Comment: `with no decimal point` ugh, I do not think you should use `double` then, rather stick to integers. `if a number have a square root with no decimal point` Great - iterate from `1` to `number / 2 (+ 1?)` and check if `i * i == number`.

Answer (score 2):

You aren’t checking for a square root.
You’re checking whether the input is divisible by its square root rounded down.
24 is divisible by 4 and thus the check passes.

Comment: Yes you're right. I'm checking the if the input is divisible by its square root to make sure the number doesn't have any decimal point. For example if square of 25 is 5, and then I get the modulus of 25 divided by 5 if it is 0 that means the number has no decimal point but is the modulus is greater than 0 that means that number has some decimal points.

Comment: You aren’t doing 24%4.8…., the argument type to the function is int so the float loses its decimal point and the operation inside the function is 24%4

Comment: But it was printing out 4.8... When using `std::cout`

Comment: Put a cout inside checkforFloat

Answer (score 0):

To determine whether a floating-point value has no decimal, just round it and check whether that changes the value:

```
bool is_integral(float f) {
    return std::round(f) == f:
}
```